# Way to tell which scripts are running on Apache

Tags: apache

Is there a way to tell which scripts are running on Apache?  My server has been hacked and someone installed a script which is sending out massive amounts of spam.  I've looked through my files and can't see anything new, I can't find out where they've hidden the script.

I really need to track down the source of all this spam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your .htaccess file to see if it's been tampered with.  Otherwise check files like index.php for unwanted code, you might lo try looking for base64_decode and eval.  These are often used to run such code.

Is this WordPress, if it is Securi provides a service that scans for and fixes this sort of thing.

Comment: I installed Securi and it did find some malware, thanks very much.